# Selecting a specific string from a text in each row using Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, extract

I have been trying to extract strings that start with the lowercase letter 'v'. It's not shown here but they are basically stock numbers(e.g. v109485). I use csv_read to create the dataframe in Python.

I have tried df['STOCKS'].str.extract, even tried to split the data and try to use str.startswith but to no avail. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STOCKS': ['v1234', 'x4567', 'v999', 'z111']})

df2 = df[df['STOCKS'].str.startswith('v')]

print(df2)
```

gives:

```
  STOCKS
0  v1234
2   v999
```